# Failure on git push, file not found /tmp/build/static

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I am having trouble with a git push to update my Heroku app. At the end of the error log this is what comes up:

```
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 105, in collect
remote:            for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 131, in list
remote:            for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 23, in get_files
remote:            directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 315, in listdir
remote:            for entry in os.scandir(path):
remote:        FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_8e6aeb15085bd120f62a7e71199f0368/static'
remote:
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
```

I have tried updating my gitignore, my settings static files location, and running git pull heroku master.

The app works perfectly well on localhost.

All help is appreciated!